# Eventcallback with dynamic change class?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have some circumstates, when i have some list with classes take example like this `List<Crews>` and `List<CrewsOnLeave>`, and i made some component where i will be using the logic there and just sends one of those two (either CrewsOnLeave or Crews), so i don't need to declare my class in the component, because here is my code

**My Code Right now**

```
    @using Models.BookingCrew

    @if (CrewonLeave.Count() > 0)
    {
    <td @onclick="SearchCrews">
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#@(modalId)">
            @CrewonLeave.Count()</span>
    </td>
    }
    else if(Crews.Count()> 0 )
    {
        <td @onclick="SearchOnLeave">
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#@(modalId)">
            @Crews.Count()</span>
    </td>
    }
    else
    {
    <td> </td>
    }

    @code{

        [Parameter]
        public string modalId{get;set;}

        [Parameter]
        public List<Crew> Crews{get; set;}
        [Parameter]
        public List<CrewOnLeave> CrewonLeave{get;set;}
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<List<CrewOnLeave>> OnLeaveClicked {get; set;}
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<List<Crew>> OnCrewsClicked {get; set;}
        private Task SearchCrews()
        {
            return OnCrewsClicked.InvokeAsync(Crews);
        }
        private Task SearchOnLeave()
        {
            return OnLeaveClicked.InvokeAsync(CrewonLeave);
        }

    }
```

My goals are to make my code more simpler like this

**Code Goal**

```
    @if (Crews.Count() > 0)
    {
    <td @onclick="SearchCrews">
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#@(modalId)">
            @Crews.Count()</span>
    </td>
    }
    else
    {
    <td> </td>
    }

    @code{

        [Parameter]
        public string modalId{get;set;}

        [Parameter]
        public List<DynamicClass> Crews{get; set;}
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<List<DynamicClass>> OnCrewsClicked {get; set;}
        private Task SearchCrews()
        {
            return OnCrewsClicked.InvokeAsync(DynamicClass);
        }
    }
```

The Problem is i don't know how to put into that `dynamic class` so the class will be dynamic when component inputed by variable list with a class.

Is there any way to make it like that?

Comment: Use an Interface implemented by both "Crews" classes. `List<ICrew>`, `EventCallback<List<ICrew>>`

Comment: as u can see, the problem is i didn't want to use it only to that both but every List<class>

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the relationship between `CrewOnLeave` and `Crew`.  If they aren't two incarnations of the same base class then you need to define an interface that the both share.  In the example the interface is blank which still works.

There's a simplified version of your code below, with to demo various methods of dealing with interface to class and class to interface conversions.

```cs
@page "/Crewzing"
<table>
    <tr>
        @if (_hasCrews)
        {
            <td @onclick="SearchCrews">
                <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#@(modalId)">
                    @Crews.Count()
                </span>
            </td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td></td>
        }

    </tr>
</table>

@code {

    public List<ICrew> Crews => CrewsOnLeave.Count > 0 ? CrewsOnLeave.Select(item => (ICrew)item).ToList() : CrewsOnBoard.Select(item => (ICrew)item).ToList();

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<ICrew>> CrewsClicked { get; set; }

    private bool _hasCrews => (this.Crews != null && this.Crews.Count > 0);

    private string modalId = "xxx";

    private void SearchCrews()
    {
        GetCrewType();
        CrewsClicked.InvokeAsync(Crews);
    }

    public interface ICrew
    {
    }

    public class CrewOnBoard : ICrew
    {
        public string Boat { get; set; }
    }

    public class CrewOnLeave : ICrew
    {
        public string Boat { get; set; }
    }

    public List<CrewOnBoard> CrewsOnBoard = new List<CrewOnBoard>()
{
        new CrewOnBoard() { Boat = "Cyclops"},
        new CrewOnBoard() { Boat = "Sirius"}
    };

    public List<CrewOnLeave> CrewsOnLeave = new List<CrewOnLeave>()
{
        new CrewOnLeave() { Boat = "Medusa"},
        new CrewOnLeave() { Boat = "Alderbaran"}
    };

    private void GetCrewType()
    {
        var c = Crews[0] ?? null;
        if (c is CrewOnBoard)
        {
            var crew = Crews.Select(item => (CrewOnBoard)item).ToList();
        }
        else if (c is CrewOnLeave)
        {
            var crew = Crews.Select(item => (CrewOnLeave)item).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```